# What does this statement mean?

Tags: php, operators

While

```
$w is an Array ( [0] => 4, [1] => 6 )
```

what does this statement mean:

```
$day == $w[0] || $day == $w[1] || $day < ((7 + $w[1] - $w[0]) % 7);
```

Please help. I have not seen the `||` operator inside other than an if or while statement. Thank you.

### EDIT 01:

This is the original function where it is used to find the number of a particular day in a date range:

```
// find number of a particular day (sunday or monday or etc) within a date range
function number_of_days($day, $start, $end){
    $w = array(date('w', $start), date('w', $end));
    return floor( ( date('z', $end) - date('z', $start) ) / 7) + ($day == $w[0] || $day == $w[1] || $day < ((7 + $w[1] - $w[0]) % 7));
}
```

This was not created by me. But I wanted to edit this function because when the end day is a Saturday, it is taking the following Sunday into account too, which is wrong.

Comment: whoever wrote this statement should be flailed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a compound boolean expression that returns `true` if any of the following four sub-expressions is `true`:

- `$day == $w[0]`
- `$day == $w[1]`
- `$day < ((7 + $w[1] - $w[0]) % 7)`

Answer (score 4):

You were right in one of your comments that the boolean expression gets added as to the integer as `1` or `0`.

If you cast a boolean value to an integer then `FALSE` gets `0` and `TRUE` gets `1`.

If you add variables with different datatypes and one of the variable is an integer, then the other variables are casted to integers, which makes:

```
var_dump(1+true);
// Result: int(2)
```

Two links that explain what happens if you use `+` on different data types and what happens if a certain datatype is casted to an integer:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting

Comment: Thank you for the links. I shall go through them. The answer which has that 'one of my comments' seems to have been deleted!

Answer (score 4):

```
$day == $w[0] || $day == $w[1] || $day < ((7 + $w[1] - $w[0]) % 7);
```

The statement will evaluate (nothing is assigned in the example) to a boolean value of true/false.

The statements are effectively computed in order

For example

```
true || false || false => true

false || false || false => false
```

This means that if any of the "subexpressions" are true then the whole expression will evaluate to true. This can be assigned to a variable `$v = expression`, or use in an `if (expression)`

Comment: Also note that if one 'subexpression' evaluates to true, the remaining 'subexpressions' are not tested anymore. This is called *short-circuiting* : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: That's something i didn't think of, very useful indeed. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

|| is the logical OR operator. Please see the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for more